# Show nth occurrence of a record

Tags: text-processing, awk

Using awk, how to show the nth occurrence of a record and delete the other occurrence, for example"

Input File:

```
79933,2
79933,4
79933,5
55251,1
49494,4
49494,2
49494,2
49494,1
```

in this example, if the desired output is the 2nd occurrence, it is will be as follow:

```
79933,4
49494,2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
n=2 awk -F, '++a[$1]==ENVIRON["n"]' <file
```

Occurrence of 1st field was track by increasing each time it was seen, saving in array `a`. If it's 2nd occurrence, the condition became true, making `awk` to print `$0`.

Comment: thank you @cuonglm, but could you explain it please?